# Updating a SQL database on an Android app with data from an SQL database on a server

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I need some help, my app created a database on creation at the minute.

What I want is to get the information in a database on a server or PC and load it into my app.
It just needs to be from server to app, not back again.

I have no idea how I would do this, does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I've been looking on google alot but cannot find any answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**first, I should say that your question is so wide**. It contains alot of technologies.
So, I'll give you a breif walk through here. you should figure out the rest on your own. and then, you can come back and ask more specific questions.

**That said, here is the path you should take:**

1. On the server, implement a REST API that respond to the caller with the data in the server database.

   > example: http://your.server.com/api/somedata
   >
   > calling this url with `GET` method should return the data you want in JSON format.
2. from your android application, call this url and save the response in a `String`.
3. parse the JSON String ( you can use [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) ).
4. save the parsed data to your local database.

If you are the one developing the server api, then this book is a recommended reading:

[RESTful Web Services](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0043D2ED6)

### Update

Say you have a table in your server database called (TABLE) with the columns COL_1, COL_2, COL_3.

You could implement a php page called 'TABLE.php' that return the following:

```
{
    "items": [
        {"COL_1": "value_1", "COL_2": "value_2", "COL_3": "value_3"},
        {"COL_1": "value_2", "COL_2": "value_3", "COL_3": "value_4"},
        {"COL_1": "value_4", "COL_2": "value_5", "COL_3": "value_6"},
        ...
    ]
}
```

In your android application call `http://your.server.com/api/TABLE.php` page with GET method, parse the JSON returned (above) and save it to your local database.

You can do this for each database table on your server, until you have all your data saved locally in your android application.

*This probably wont be the best design decision, but considering your knowledge about the topics, this could be a fair starting point*.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Trying to get my head around this so sorry for the stupid questions.
if i was using a wamp server would i be able to just onCreate just get the database as a sting and use gson to convert it?Does that make sence?

Comment: i have this running at the minute 
http://192.168.0.4/android_connect/employee.php
(can you see that?)
and this is what i have trying to access it,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15911735/need-some-help-android-app
could you see whats wrong with it?

Comment: **first**, i modified (corrected) the JSON returned (my mistake:)). each line for a row in the table. **second**, the url for the php page is broken. from the ip value, it seems you are running it from a local server on your development machine. you need to put it on an online server. and, i'll have a look at your other question.

Comment: thanks for your help, i've sort of confused myself so much i dont even know what i have anymore. everyone is really helpful on this but give different advice so i'm not sure if this will work now

Comment: :) .. take it easy .. THIS WILL WORK .. I saw your other question .. you are almost there!. just paste the JSON returned from your php page there in your other question and point out the 'line 55' for the people there. don't get frustrated that easy :)

Comment: thanks for the advaice, i dont really know how i did it but it works. thanks for all the help

Answer (score 0):

Using HttpClient you can set things up to execute a POST to some servlet or similar app on the server. That app needs to then send data  back to your Android app which is waiting for a response from the server.  Then your app can parse the data and stuff it's own database.

Comment: Sorry i didnt see this had been answered. Thank you for the reply. How would i parse the data? Is there set functions? Im sorry i just really have no idea how to go about it